# How do I know I've hit a save point in Ratchet & Clank: All 4 One?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one

I recently loaded up my single player game to discover I had to re-do a large section of a level; apparently I didn't progress completely through a section though I thought I had. I thought once I found the scannerbot (where you are given a summary of bolts/enemies/pets/etc.) that was a "save point", but that wasn't the case as I was getting out of the training area for the Vac-U 4000.

What should I look for to indicate I've completed a section of the game, and would be a good place to pick it up again later?

Comment: I have been having the same exact problem. Everything I read says that the game is supposed to save automatically, but I have yet to actually have it save. Anybody out there have an real SOLUTION to this? Because so far no one seems to have any answers, they just keep quoting from the game manual. HELP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, the game saves every time a Scanning Minion (and thus the totals screen) shows up.

Comment: I thought so too, but then at the end of the Vac-U training session there is a Scanning Minion that didn't save my place... not sure what the deal was there, maybe it was an anomaly?